# Understanding homework solution - why are $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ joint WSS, and finding Wiener filter + error

Tags: modulation, demodulation, random-process

I'm walking through the published solutions of my homework and I'm struggling interpreting them. In them I was given a random Gaussian process  $\{X_t\}$ and a random variable

$$\{Y_t\} = X_t\cos(2\pi f_0t+\Theta), \quad \Theta \sim \mathcal{U}_{[0,2\pi]}, $$ i.e., $\Theta$ is a random phase.

It is also given that $S_x(f)$ is defined as $0$ for $|f| \geq F_0/2$, and that $f_0 = 100F_0$

- The solution assumes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are Joint Wide Sense Stationary, why is that the case?
- afterwards the question defines $\{Z_t\} = Y_t\cos(2\pi f_0t+\Theta)$ and asks to find the optimal linear filter of $\{X_t\}$ out of $\{Z_t\}$, and finding the error.

I've found: $$S_z(f) =\frac{1}{4} S_x(f) + \frac{1}{16}S_x(f+2f_0) + S_x(f-2f_0)$$ and $$S_{zx}(f) = \frac{1}{2} S_x(f)$$
The solution based on these two results states $H(f) = 2$, and that the error would be 0 for $|f| \leq F$ - I'm struggling to see why.

Comment: Does jointly WSS imply that the processes are _individually_ WSS too? If so, is $\{Y_t\}$ a WSS process? It seems that $\{X_t\}$ is given to be a WSS process since its PSD is specified.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I always understood "jointly {*stationarity constraint*}" to be a requirement on the process $Z_t := X_t Y_t$ AND the joint CDF $F_{X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \ldots, Y_{u_1}, Y_{u_2}, \ldots}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, y_1, y_2,\ldots)$. So, for WSS, the boundedness constraints on the first two moments apply to $Z$, the correlation properties to the joint PDF. That way, you can have something like a dependent process $Y$ "compensating" the "annoying" properties of e.g. a Cauchy-distributed process $X$; that is a relevant tool when modelling things like "clipping".

Comment: @MarcusMüller The questions were addressed to the OP, not to you. Also, the question was about WSS processes, and your response is about joint _stationarity_ which is not at all the same thing.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you lost me there. The question was about "jointly WSS", which I exactly addressed in that comment (I am well aware the question was for OP, but I think the question is misleading, because for jointly WSS; individual processes don't need to be WSS, as I remarked)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Some people don't agree with your assertion that jointly WSS npricesses don't need to be individually WSS.  See, for example, https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter10/10_1_4_stationary_processes.php

Comment: my textbook defines WSS as a process for which $\mu_x$ isn't dependent on time, and the autocorrelation is dependent only on time differences and not time itself. two processes are called JWSS if they fulfill requirement for WSS individually, and $E[Y_{t+\tau}X_{t}]$ is only dependent on $\tau$. apologies for the delayed response

Comment: @Piratemetaldrinkingcrew no harm done! well, your book agrees with Dilip's definition, not with mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that the OP has responded with his textbook's definition of jointly wide-sense-stationary (WSS) processes as those that are individually WSS and whose cross-correlation function $R_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2)$ depends only on the difference $t_1-t_2$ of the arguments, let's consider his questions.

1. The solution assumes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are Joint Wide Sense Stationary, why is that the case?

Well,  $\{X_t\}$ is assumed to be WSS since its PSD is specified (as being band-limited to $\left(-\frac{F_0}{2},+\frac{F_0}{2}\right)$. Now, \begin{align}
E[Y_t]&=E[X_t\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)]\\
&= E[X_t]E[\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)] & \Theta, X_t~ \text{independent}\\
&= E[X_t]\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2\pi f_0t + \theta)\cdot \frac 1{2\pi} \mathrm d\theta & \Theta \sim \mathcal U[0,2\pi]$\\
&= 0
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
E[Y_sY_t] &= E[X_s\cos(2\pi f_0s + \Theta)X_t\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)]\\
&= E[X_sX_t]E[\cos(2\pi f_0s + \Theta)\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)]\\
&= R_X(s-t)\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2\pi f_0s + \theta)\cos(2\pi f_0t + \theta)\cdot \frac 1{2\pi} \mathrm d\theta\\
&= \frac 12 R_X(s-t)\cos(s-t)
\end{align}
and so $\{Y_t\}$ is a WSS process too. Turning to the cross-correlation function, we have
\begin{align}
E[X_sY_t] &= E[X_sX_t\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)]\\
&= E[X_sX_t]E[\cos(2\pi f_0t + \Theta)]\\
&= R_X(s-t)\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(2\pi f_0t + \theta)\cdot \frac 1{2\pi} \mathrm d\theta\\
&= 0
\end{align}
and so $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are *uncorrelated* WSS processes, and thus are (trivially) jointly WSS processes.  Note that this is just modulation of the (low-pass) $\{X_t\}$ process onto a high-frequency carrier ($f_0 = 100F_0$) to produce the band-pass process $\{Y_t\}$ whose PSD is nonzero only in the frequency bands of width $F_0$ centered around $\pm f_0$.

Turning to the second question, $Z_t$ is the output of the mixer that demodulates $\{Y_t\}$ back down to baseband, and the optimal filtering of this mixer output to complete the demodulation process is just discarding the double-frequency terms. An ideal LPF with cut-off $\frac{F_0}{2}$ minimizes the noise in the demodulator output.

I have no clue what $H(f)=2$ means in the OP's book solution. I suspect that what is meant is an ideal LPF of bandwidth $\frac{F_0}2$ and passband gain $2$.  Passing the $\{Z_t\}$ process (whose PSD is $S_Z(f) =\frac{1}{4} S_X(f) + \frac{1}{16}S_X(f+2f_0) + S_X(f-2f_0)$ through this filter produces a process with PSD $S_X(f)$, which is (mean-square) equivalent to $\{X_t\}$.

Comment: thank you! why does a band limited PSD mean that a process is WSS? as for $H(f)$ It's the transmission function of the wiener filter. I think I understand what you mean by discarding higher frequency terms - thank you for your detailed and clear reply!

Comment: Non-WSS processes don't have PSDs in the usual sense that one interprets PSD as the Fourier transform of the (univariate) ACF. For a Non-WSS process, the ACF is a function of two time variables, and the notion of PSD is more complicated. So, given the PSD of $\{X_t\}$ without any other bells and whistles indicating that the process is **not** a WSS process and must be handled differently, it is reasonable to assume that $\{X_t\}$ is indeed a  WSS process. If you don't agree with this assumption, my whole answer becomes irrelevant. (Obviously the creator of your HW solutions agrees with me!)

Comment: That's a really good answer - thank you! I never thought of it that way